# Android apk "unable to install" on Blackberry 10.2.1

Tags: android, apk, blackberry-10, blackberry-android

I have signed my Android application by :

```
Right click on project -> Android Tools -> Export Signed Application package
```

And tried to install that apk file on my Blackberry 10.2.1 but getting `"unable to install"` error.

Also tried to export application normally by just right click and Export and directly exported the application with new `KeyStore`, but same result I got.

Can anyone suggest what wrong am I doing?

Comment: Are you sure you tried the signed apk? Once signed, I never had any issues installing them

Comment: Yes i created signed apk using both the above methods but still it didn't work..can u tell by which steps you created a signed apk for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally this is due to issues in your android manifest! Are you trying to access features not supported by BB10?

Check (or post here) your manifest and try to install it on an Android device to eliminate any other issues.

Comment: You are right, In the name of the application I was having "\n" to display the app name in two lines. That was creating the issue. I removed that and it worked fine. Thnx a ton!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is not enough place on your phone?

usually it's easy as i see [here](http://n4bb.com/install-android-apks-blackberry-10-2-1/)

Comment: I have tried installing it on a device and one simulator..both didn't work, so i guess this might not be the case..anyway thnx for the answer..

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps assuming you have the BlackBerry 10.2 plugin installed and that you want to put this app on BlackBerry App World:

1) Right click and select BlackBerry Tools (just under Android Tools) and make sure to 'Add BlackBerry Nature'

2) To sign just right click, select BlackBerry Tools then Sign for BlackBerry World.

You may need to configure signing keys in Eclipse->Preferences->BlacKberry if you haven't already.

Comment: Well that wasn't needed really, but thanx for the answer.